# How to restart this jQuery slider after the last div img reach

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Here is simple jQuery slider, but i want to set this as when the last img div reach then if we click on `next` it should be return to the first one again and same as if we are going to back side with the previous button the if the first img div reach then it should be return as last one same as backside.

i tried this code but it not working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.next').click(function(){
var active = $('.slide .active');

 if(active.next('div').length != 0) {
    $('.slide').find('div.active').next().
        addClass('active');
$('.slide').find('div.active').prev().
        removeClass('active');
        }
        else {
        $('#slide div:first').addClass('active');
        }

});
$('.prev').click(function(){
 if(active.prev('div').length != 0) {
    $('.slide').find('div.active').prev().
        addClass('active');
$('.slide').find('div.active').next().
        removeClass('active');
   }
      else {
        $('#slide div:last').addClass('active');
        }
   
   
});
});
```

My whole slider code is:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.next').click(function(){
    $('.slide').find('div.active').next().
        addClass('active');
$('.slide').find('div.active').prev().
        removeClass('active');

});
$('.prev').click(function(){
    $('.slide').find('div.active').prev().
        addClass('active');
$('.slide').find('div.active').next().
        removeClass('active');

});
});
```

```css
.container {
position: relative;
width: 600px;
height: 400px;
background: yellow;
}
.container .slide {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
Left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
Z-index: 2;
}

.container .slide div
{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
Left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
}

.container .slide div img

{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
Left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
}

.container .slide div.active
{
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="slide">
<div class="active"><img src="https://images.tv9hindi.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/LPG-Gas-Cylinder.jpg?w=600&dpr=6.4"></div>
<div><img src="https://static.india.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/LPG-Price-Hike.jpg"></div>
<div><img src="https://hindi.cdn.zeenews.com/hindi/sites/default/files/2021/10/31/958129-indian-railways-time-tables.jpg"></div>
<div><img src="https://new-img.patrika.com/upload/2020/10/27/cylinder1_6484690_835x547-m.jpg"></div>
</div>
</div>

<button class="prev">prev</button>
<button class="next">next</button>
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could also use one of the countless free casousel plugins, like [Slick](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). They already have everything figured out for you.

Comment: How can i solve my issue at this time without Slick tell me plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When clicking on next - check if the last div [has the class](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) `active`. If so remove it and add it to the first div. When clicking on prev - do the opposite.

Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.next').click(function(){
  $('.slide').find('div.active').next().addClass('active');
  $('.slide').find('div.active').prev().removeClass('active');
  if ($('.slide div:last-of-type').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.slide div:last-of-type').removeClass('active');
    $('.slide div:first-of-type').addClass('active');
  }
});
$('.prev').click(function(){
  $('.slide').find('div.active').prev().addClass('active');
  $('.slide').find('div.active').next().removeClass('active');
  if ($('.slide div:first-of-type').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.slide div:first-of-type').removeClass('active');
    $('.slide div:last-of-type').addClass('active');
  }
});
});
```

```css
.container {
position: relative;
width: 600px;
height: 400px;
background: yellow;
}
.container .slide {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
Left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
Z-index: 2;
}

.container .slide div
{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
Left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
}

.container .slide div img

{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
Left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
}

.container .slide div.active
{
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="slide">
<div class="active"><img src="https://images.tv9hindi.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/LPG-Gas-Cylinder.jpg?w=600&dpr=6.4"></div>
<div><img src="https://static.india.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/LPG-Price-Hike.jpg"></div>
<div><img src="https://hindi.cdn.zeenews.com/hindi/sites/default/files/2021/10/31/958129-indian-railways-time-tables.jpg"></div>
<div><img src="https://new-img.patrika.com/upload/2020/10/27/cylinder1_6484690_835x547-m.jpg"></div>
</div>
</div>

<button class="prev">prev</button>
<button class="next">next</button>
```

Comment: really How the magic happen i am tried from last few hours i love you

Comment: @RKS LOL. If you can remove, add and toggle classes - sure you can check if element got class the same way (:

Comment: can you help me for how can i slide left and slide right effect when we click on next and previous button

Comment: @RKS this is not how it work here. You should try to do that yourself and if you got specific question - ask it on new thread... Hint: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Comment: @ A. Meshu sir plz check this plz plz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70042321/after-content-update-from-ajax-jquery-not-work-properly